A fantasy book about a main character named Draco
Looking for a book I read some time ago but didn't get a chance to finish. This is what I know:

Might be a series of novels
Main character named Draco
Set in a fantasy realm
Draco is royalty
He ends up traveling with a woman
There are three races: Human, bird people and demons I believe.
They must avoid Demons
One of the Demons is a woman and she has an army of bird children
Bird children were described as having bird like legs and bird wings with tiny human hands on the end, along with a mix of a human and bird face such as a beak for a nose.
Draco somehow joins up with an army and travels through a desert or plain
Everyone must construct a shield because the Demons can invoke horrible thoughts (I think they end up going crazy and killing themselves)
There was something about a half breed baby being born


Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

The bird people sound like Kenku, and the need for shields against demons reminds me of R. A. Salvatore's Demon Wars series, but no one named Draco.

There's a Māori myth similar to this: Hatupatu and Kurangaituku (AKA Hatupatu and the Bird Woman). The rock from the story is beside a road nearish to the famous geothermal area of Rotorua.
